# ngTableParams parameter "page" is number, why it must be a "page()" in getdata

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

This GitHub "[Configurating your table with ngTableParams](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/wiki/Configuring-your-table-with-ngTableParams#parameters)" clearly defines "page" of parameters is type number. However, its use in getdata becomes ".page()", a function.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe this is the ROOT of the answer even though it's for [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In initial config object for ngTableParams object is `page` property.

```
this.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}
```

but next, `this.tableParams` is instance of ngTableParams, which has method `page` defined here https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/dist/ng-table.js#L159

Function `getData` has as second argument ngTableParams instance, not config object.

Comment: more confused. 
You are saying page() and page property are two diff "page", and there are two ngTableParams too, right? If so, How do users like me know when to use which?